# Parrallax scrolling background code to target multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have this code which will work for the background image of the body but I want to extend its functionality to also change the background position of many divs at once on the same page. I'm trying to fiddle with the selector but not having much luck

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
        $('body').css('background-attachment', 'fixed');
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "50% " + ( 1800 + (Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop) / 2 )) + "px";
        });
    });
    </script>

    CODE I'M TRYING TO GET TO WORK
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
            $('body').css('background-attachment', 'fixed');
            $(window).scroll(function () {
            $( ".parrallax" ).style.backgroundPosition = "50% " + ( 1800 + (Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop) / 2 )) + "px";
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div class="parrallax" style="background-image: url('http://www.g1dental.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/dental.png');">
```

Comment: many divs on the same page? I only see 1 div in your example

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the background position being changed. When you start scrolling you will see the value being updated. When you decide what divs you want on the page you can easily use this same logic to update their background position.

http://jsfiddle.net/e6wd9fjt/

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(readyevent) {
            $('body').css('background-attachment', 'fixed');
            $(window).scroll(function (scrollevent) {

                    $(".parrallax").css('background-position', '0px '+ (Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop) / 2 ) + "px");
                $('#background_position').text($(".parrallax").css('background-position'));
        });

});
```